# What new features does vs2010 professional bring for developers targeting .net 3.5 or .net 2.0 over vs2008 professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to convince my department of the value of vs2010 for the future release, however i'm having a hard time that compares professional against professional and what all the new features are, particularly if we have any red tape with being able to deploy .net 4.0 applications while that waits to get approval.

The microsoft site seems to want to just talk about the new features of vs2010 in general without being specific about product level comparisons.

I'm still interested in knowing the new features that would apply to targeting 4.0, but my easiest sell will be the features we will get without targeting it. What's new/improved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885955/whats-the-compelling-reason-to-upgrade-to-visual-studio-2010-from-vs2008

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks, but that forum is way less specific, and the features are not really specifying which I would get without a team version, or without access to .net 4.0 if that was the case.

Comment: It's less specific, but it's essentially a subset of that question and thus it's considered a dupe IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coolest feature I have seen is historical debugging.

You can let an error occur, and then step back in your code to the point it started, as if you just happened to have a breakpoint in the right place.

As far as I know it works for all versions of .NET, and could be a real time saver.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/05/20/visual-studio-2010-historical-debugging.aspx